# Бибилиотека Python для конвертации текста в картинку

Tags: python, python-3.x, изображения, поиск-библиотек

Всем привет! Поиск не дал результатов по задаче:
есть текст, например:

```
Иван Сидоров
```

Возможно ли его конвертировать в картинку (jpg, png итд без разницы)? Чтобы на выходе была картинка с любым фоном (или без) и текст `Иван Сидоров` например посередине картинки?

Comment: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @Эникейщик благодарю!

Comment: @babyborn [Тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1565888/562052)

Answer (score 0):

Это задача решается и без питона:

```bash
magick -background purple -fill green -font 'Ubuntu' -pointsize 72 label:'Кислота' label.gif
```

[image: результат]

Но если нужен питон:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['magick',
 '-background',
 'purple',
 '-fill',
 'green',
 '-font',
 'Ubuntu',
 '-pointsize',
 '72',
 'label:Кислота',
 'label.gif'])
```

Только не забудь imagemagick поставить.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте библиотеку Pillow (Fork):

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
image = Image.new('RGB', (500, 500), (255, 255, 255)) # Создаем новое изображение
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image) # Создаем объект для рисования
font = ImageFont.truetype('arial.ttf', 36) # Загружаем шрифт
draw.text((100, 100), 'Иван Сидоров', font=font, fill=(0, 0, 0)) # Рисуем текст
image.save('output.png') # Сохраняем изображение
```